# jquery Ajax nested inside a previous Ajax success fn not updating DOM

Tags: jquery

**Desired Outcome:**
The 2nd ajax call should inject returned data into the DOM at div #co_label.

- The first alert() has correct data in it
- the 2nd alert() shows that the correct information has been returned by the 2nd ajax call. However, that data is not injected into the DOM.
- There are no console errors in Chrome's debugger

jQuery / Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', '.mledit', function(event) {
    var company_id = this.id.split( 'editcopro_' )[1];
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/ax_all_ajax_fns.php",
        data: 'request=edit_company_data&company_id='+company_id,
        success:function(data){
            $('#co_label').html(data);
            var client_user_id = company_id;

            $('#co_label').dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                height: 600,
                width: 800,
                modal: true,
                buttons: 
                    {
                        Okay: function() {
                            //Var defs for cn, cp, cw, ct, a1, etc.
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "ajax/ax_all_ajax_fns.php",
                                data: 'request=update_edited_company_data&client_user_id='+client_user_id+'&co_name='+cn+'&co_phone1='+cp+'&co_website='+cw+'&co_city='+ct+'&co_addr1='+a1+'&co_addr2='+a2+'&co_acct_name='+an+'&co_acct_phone='+ap+'&co_acct_email='+ae+'&co_prov='+pv+'&co_pcode='+pc+'&co_country='+co+'&notes='+co_notes,
                                success: function(data) {
                                    $( '#alert' ).html( data );
                                    $( '#alert' ).dialog( 'open' );

                                    $.ajax({
                                        type: "POST",
                                        url: "ajax/ax_all_ajax_fns.php",
                                        data: 'request=update_edited_mailing_label&user_level='+user_level+'&user_id=' + user_id+'&user_type=' + user_type,
                                        success:function(data){
                                            $('#label_top').html(data);
                                        }
                                    });
                                } //End success
                            }); //End ajax[update_edited_company_data]
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        },
                        Cancel: function() {
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                            window.location = '';
                        }
                    }
            })
        }
    });
});
```

UPDATE:

I've just noticed this: Looking through Chrome Developer and/or Firebug, the entire #co_label DIV is missing from the document after the JQueryUI dlg closes. Something appears to be happening between this line:

```
$('#co_label').html(data);
```

and this line:

```
$('#co_label').dialog({
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using .html(data) have you tried using .val(data) as such:

```
 $('#co_label').val(data);
```

The [API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) notes you cannot use .html() when dealing with XML which may not be the issue, but I've run into issues using .html before and have used .val instead.  If you're just inserting non-HTML-formatted data into an empty ID, .val() should work for you.

Comment: Thank you - good thought, but no joy. Same result, sadly. I updated question with a new bit of info, though, in case that adds any new clues.